# How to add unique identifier column in table?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table which does not have any unique identifier . I want to add unique column to table , how can I achieve this?

My table looks like this:

```
name age     gender      marital_status
SAM          M           Single
BOB          M           Married
JEN          F           Single
BOB          M           Married
```

I want my table to be like this:

```
id      name age     gender      marital_status
1        SAM          M           Single
2        BOB          M           Married
3        JEN          F           Single
4        BOB          M           Married
```

The reason I want to have unique identifier is because some of the records are duplicates of each other and I want to remove the duplicates .

Comment: Adding a uid won't remove duplicates; you'll still need to do that, and have logic that will prevent duplicates from being added. You may already know all that but it's not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
alter table t add id int;

create sequence t_seq;

update t set id = t_seq.nextval;

alter table t modify id primary key;
```

Unfortunately, I don't think Oracle allows you to put the column at the beginning of the column list.  It is always added to the end.

Comment: Thanks Gordon. It helps , ya it always put at the end but logic works so its fine.

Answer (score 0):

Demo table:

```
create table people (name, gender, marital_status)
as
select 'SAM', 'M', 'Single' from dual union all
select 'BOB', 'M', 'Married' from dual union all
select 'JEN', 'F', 'Single' from dual union all
select 'BOB', 'M', 'Married' from dual;
```

Add the identity column (requires Oracle 12.1 or later):

```
alter table people add id integer generated always as identity;
```

If you want to, rearrange the dictionary order so that the new column appears first when you describe the table (also requires Oracle 12.1):

```
begin
    for r in (
        select column_name from user_tab_columns c
        where  c.table_name = 'PEOPLE'
        and    c.column_name <> 'ID'
        order by c.column_id
    )
    loop
        execute immediate 'alter table people modify ' || r.column_name || ' invisible';
        execute immediate 'alter table people modify ' || r.column_name || ' visible';
    end loop;
end;
/
```

Comment: Great . you are awesome